# russian option for babel breaks Inconsolata

Tags: babel, russian, inconsolata

OK:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{zi4}

\begin{document}
\Huge \texttt{I need only latin here} % I see Inconsolata here
\end{document}
```

Not OK:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{zi4}

\begin{document}
\Huge \texttt{I need only latin here}
\end{document}
```

The latter one differs only in babel option `russian` and yields strange result: CM font in some bright version.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? (Namely, use both, Inconsolata and `russian` option for babel.)

PS I'm using TeX Live 2015.

Comment: There's no support for Cyrillic in Inconsolata. Do you only need Latin characters in the monospaced font?

Comment: @egreg yes, I do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the `russian` option is in force, the output font encoding is set to T2A and there's no support for this encoding with Inconsolata and LaTeX uses a fallback font

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/zi4/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.
```

If you only need Latin characters in the monospaced font, the best is to define a new command:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[OT1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{zi4}

\newcommand{\latinttfamily}{\fontencoding{OT1}\ttfamily}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\ltexttt}{\latinttfamily}

\begin{document}
\Huge Спасибо \ltexttt{abc}
\end{document}
```

One could also redefine `\texttt`.

[image]